# RBAC: roles with multiple namespaces

Tags: kubernetes, ansible, yaml, rbac

Trying to write my first set of RBAC roles. So trying to figure out the best way to have 2 roles for multiple namespaced components.

Admin-role (RW for 3 namespaces say default, ns1 & ns2)
user-role (Read-only for 3 namespaces say default, ns1 & ns2)

Was thinking will need a service account with 2 clusterRoles for admin/user

```
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: ServiceAccount
metadata:
  name: sa
  namespace: default

apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: ClusterRole
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  name: admin-master
rules:
- apiGroups:
    - batch
  resources:
    - pods
  verbs:
    - create
    - delete
    - deletecollection
    - get
    - list
    - patch
    - update
    - watch

apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: ClusterRole
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  name: user-master
rules:
- apiGroups:
    - batch
  resources:
    - pods
  verbs:
    - get
    - list
    - watch
```

Then make use of roleBindings:

```
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: RoleBinding
metadata:
  name: admin-rw
  namespace: ns1
roleRef:
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
  kind: ClusterRole
  name: admin-master
subjects:
  - kind: ServiceAccount
    name: sa
    namespace: default
---
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: RoleBinding
metadata:
  name: user-readonly
  namespace: ns1
roleRef:
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
  kind: ClusterRole
  name: user-master
subjects:
  - kind: ServiceAccount
    name: sa
    namespace: default
```

But not sure how the best way to bind roles admin-rw/user-readonly with namespace 2 (ns2)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Roles are scoped, either bound to an specific namespace or cluster-wide. For namespace-scoped roles, [you can just simply deploy the same role in multiple namespaces](https://www.cncf.io/blog/2018/08/01/demystifying-rbac-in-kubernetes/).

The idea behind this is to have partitioned permissions in the cluster, although [it implies more administrative effort](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/rbac/#service-account-permissions) but is a safer practice.

Additionally, in your definition, you're trying to bind permissions to specific namespaces, however, you're using `ClusterRole` which is a [cluster-scoped resource](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/rbac/#role-and-clusterrole). You might want to change that to `Role` if you want namespace-scoped permissions.

You might find this [CNCF article](https://www.cncf.io/blog/2018/08/01/demystifying-rbac-in-kubernetes/) useful on this matter.

Comment: A cluster role doesn't imply that Service Account will have cluster-wide permissions. You can add ClusterRole named `edit` to ServiceAccount and this ServiceAccount will be scoped to one namespace.

Answer (score -1):

This answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/57729174/2660452 is wrong.

`ClusterRole` and `Role` defines which resources you can operated. if your role need to manage resources in multiple namespaces, you need to use `ClusterRole`

and `RoleBinding` defines which namespace your account will be granted.

here is the example from official document: https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/rbac/#rolebinding-example

> A RoleBinding can also reference a ClusterRole to grant the permissions defined in that ClusterRole to resources inside the RoleBinding's namespace. This kind of reference lets you define a set of common roles across your cluster, then reuse them within multiple namespaces.
>
> For instance, even though the following RoleBinding refers to a ClusterRole, "dave" (the subject, case sensitive) will only be able to read Secrets in the "development" namespace, because the RoleBinding's namespace (in its metadata) is "development".
>
> ```
> apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
> # This role binding allows "dave" to read secrets in the "development" namespace.
> # You need to already have a ClusterRole named "secret-reader".
> kind: RoleBinding
> metadata:
>   name: read-secrets
>   #
>   # The namespace of the RoleBinding determines where the permissions are granted.
>   # This only grants permissions within the "development" namespace.
>   namespace: development
> subjects:
> - kind: User
>   name: dave # Name is case sensitive
>   apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
> roleRef:
>   kind: ClusterRole
>   name: secret-reader
>   apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
> ```

Comment: You presented yaml with a scope of one namespace. OP asks how to write yaml that has a wider scope, for example, two specific namespaces.